# How to log intermediate messages (log lines) in API Connect?

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

By default, only the received request and the transmitted response gets logged for API's build in API Connect. But in case we need to log intermediate messages we need to pass below HTTP header in request to log the debug messages.

```
Apim-Debug:true
```

But we cannot ask the external systems to sent this header in request, which is not involved in the functionality. How can we implement this debug logging? Is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, your question is likely to get closed because it does not meet the criteria for questions.  Please see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Though this is a very old thread, but I am still unaware of the solution. Can anyone please answer the same. @Chris Snow, this a genuine problem and we have even raised SR for the same. Please let me know if you need any more details in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is potentially no way presently and its suggested to send these intermediate responses to some logging facility. One can also create an intermediate API and use activity logging in that.

Refer to the below thread for further discussions:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/457253/api-connect-analytics-logging.html